# How to create your own Magento mobile application for android and iphone

Tags: android, iphone, web-applications, magento-1.6

Please any One who has worked on Magento Site's App Development help me to get a direction to move further as I am totally lost and getting nothing from the Online Research.

Any help would be highly Appreciated.

Thanks And Regards.

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/demo   

Look here also the demo is provided.

Comment: If anyone looking for how to create a magento app use this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112174/android-connect-to-magento/25947581#25947581

Comment: Why don't you use the out of the box solution Mofluid for building your native mobile app?
It's open source source and you can change code as per your requirements.

Here is the link to their site - http://mofluid.com/

Comment: There are many mobile app builder you may use http://mobikul.com/

Comment: More ways to create your magento app. A best way is Customization. You  can add modification or update any latest features is possible only in this method. Contus m Comm is readily built solution for magento mobile app. Just visit here - http://www.contus.com/magento-mobile-app.php

Comment: You can build a magento app either by 3rd Party Developer or through an app builder. 3rd Party development would be costly compared to develop an app through an app buider. Moreover you may save a lot of time through an app builder. Visit here - http://cedcommerce.com/blog/magento/magento-apps/magenative-magento-mobile-app/

Comment: Several options are available to create an iOS and Android native mobile app builder for eCommerce platform. One of the prominent ones is: https://www.knowband.com/mobile-app/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are few Steps for that::

1. Magento offers two API's to develop your app in Android
                a. **SOAP API**
                b. **XML-RPC**
2. If you want to use `XMLRPC API`,then you have to download **it's library** and use it in your Project.
3. You have to create a New User in your `Magento Store` with **roles**.That you can do by **loging** in to your **Admin module** and the option is under the `system->WebServices->User && Roles`...You have to create first roles and then create a user and assign the roles to the User.
4. You have to use the `UserName` and `APIKey` that you give in the `Magento` Store for calling the **login Function.**
5. Calling the Login function,you will Receive a **Session Id**,that you have to **store** and **Use** it in your **further calls**.

Some of the helpful links to **get Started** Are::

6. [Link-1](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api)
7. [Link-2](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/255191/)
8. [Link-3](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/consuming-the-magento-xmlrpc-web-service-through-android/)
9. [Link-4](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/android-magento-mobile-boilerplate/)
10. [My Questions And their Solutions On SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155805/haresh-chaudhary?tab=questions)

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the answer. Can you tell me which one of these will be faster: Performance wise. I once asked if we can make our own custom frontend using the API's instead of Magento's default and everyone seemed to dislike the idea. Doesn't that mean the same thing for the mobile applications?

Comment: You only have 2 Options,use XMLRPC or SOAP..or the third one..create your own one...But XMLRPC is better according to me as Simple to Use than Other..this statement is made with reference of ME.

Comment: You can use a cross platform app builder such as Phonegap and create front-end there. For back-end you can create web-services using XML RPC APIs. Phonegap will create a cross platform app and you will not need to build separate apps for both.

Some of the extensions that are built using the same approach are Mofluid - http://mofluid.com and official magento app - https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/mobile

Comment: Magento is an opensource, So first you need to create an application, Then it ll attached with your magento app & synchronized to your application. Otherwise you need readymade API, i suggest Contus MComm. They bulit a readymade application for Magento mobile apps

Comment: I think the links are broken!