# android connect to magento

Tags: android, magento

i am using eclipse for development of android application. i want to connect my application to magento. i am new developer so i have not too much idea about this.

below i mention some problem which i want to solve:-

1. my database is in mysql and mysql connect to magento. so how my app connect to magento?
2. if i  connect my app to magento through web service but i have no idea about how to connect through web service to magento?

please help me

Answer (score 2):

If anyone looking for android application for magento site, you can use this.

Magento offers two API's to develop your app in Android

1. SOAP API - http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html
2. REST API - http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html
3. You have to create a New User in your Magento Store with roles.That you can do by loging in to your Admin and the option is under the system->WebServices->User&Roles.
4. You have to create role and a user.Then assign the roles to the User.
5. For using SOAP API use this tutorial http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/android-development/magento-v2-api-soap-android/
6. For REST api use - [Android - Magento REST Api Cannot Respond Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079685/android-magento-rest-api-cannot-respond-properly/25094176#25094176)
7. In REST API, Oauth is there This example is without Oauth.

Before stating Android side make sure the magento configured properly. Test the urls in browser first then use it in Application.

Answer (score -4):

For those who are still looking at answer, I have put down my research in below link, we were able to sucessfully create mobile app for IOS and andriod with libraries mentioned in below link..please go through once..

http://www.siddharthvaghasia.com/2014/12/11/connect-ios-and-andriod-app-to-magento-store/

For andriod...here is steps with example..
http://www.siddharthvaghasia.com/2014/12/14/use-k2soap-library-android-platform-consume-magento-soap-api-v2/

Note- Not able to add to comment to posted in answer...