# How to connect Magento REST Api with Android Application?

Tags: php, android, rest, magento, e-commerce

I have a e-commerce website which uses Magento. How can I use the REST API on Magento to connect to my Android Application?

Comment: please tell me about your json rest api or provide url , request and response formate

Comment: New consumer is created in magento server as per this documentation(http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/authentication/oauth_configuration.html). Now I struck with giving callbackurl and rejected callback url.  How to make the calback url for android app to receive the data through response from webservice?

Comment: don't worry you can put any url in callback it is only used for OAuth 2.0 to notify your request is served successfully and for implementation details i provide you a link in android

Comment: Please take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112174/android-connect-to-magento/25947581#25947581

Comment: @USKMobility Its working as public Api. I can able to view the data by parsing it. But, how to implement OAuth Authorization in it? Please guide in this regard.

Comment: removed random bolding and irrelevant comments

Comment: @USKMobility I got my android app registered in Magento Store and got 'key' and 'secret'.
1. Through that i got the 'Request Token'
2. Via Request token i got the 'AuthorizationUrl'
3. But it need the admin login username and password manually to get the verification code bu which i get the access token.
4. My point is that when every launch how the app 'Guest Users' do the admin login to see the basic home page itself?
5. Please guide me through this.

Comment: venkat r i am not getting your point , what is the meaning of app Guest users and admin, it is part of your application or android OS

Comment: @USKMobility I got authorization by the admin manually and somehow i got the accessToken. But i was authorized as the role of "Guest". As a Guest i can access only the product details. But, there are customers already having an account through website. So how to make those existing customers to access their account through my android app also? As a "Guest" i can't access the customer details like their "id", "name". For that i need to get the access as "customer" role. That what i'm asking how to get Authorization as customer login access? Then only, i can maintain customer history, session.

Answer (score 0):

Complete sample for calling restful webservice 
    RestFulWebservice.java this activity class

```
public class RestFulWebservice extends Activity {


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rest_ful_webservice);  

        final Button GetServerData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GetServerData);

        GetServerData.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // WebServer url change it accordingly
                String serverURL = "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/JsonReturn.php";

                // Use AsyncTask execute Method To Prevent ANR Problem
                new LongOperation().execute(serverURL);
            }
        });    

    }


    // Class with extends AsyncTask class

    private class LongOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        // Required initialization

        private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        private String Content;
        private String Error = null;
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(RestFulWebservice.this);
        String data =""; 
        TextView uiUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
        TextView jsonParsed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jsonParsed);
        int sizeData = 0;  
        EditText serverText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.serverText);


        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

            //Start Progress Dialog (Message)

            Dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
            Dialog.show();

            try{
                // Set Request parameter
                data +="&" + URLEncoder.encode("data", "UTF-8") + "="+serverText.getText();

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

        }

        // Call after onPreExecute method
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

            /************ Make Post Call To Web Server ***********/
            BufferedReader reader=null;

                 // Send data 
                try
                { 

                   // Defined URL  where to send data
                   URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

                  // Send POST data request

                  URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 
                  conn.setDoOutput(true); 
                  OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 
                  wr.write( data ); 
                  wr.flush(); 

                  // Get the server response 

                  reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                  String line = null;

                    // Read Server Response
                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                               // Append server response in string
                               sb.append(line + "
");
                        }

                    // Append Server Response To Content String 
                   Content = sb.toString();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Error = ex.getMessage();
                }
                finally
                {
                    try
                    {

                        reader.close();
                    }

                    catch(Exception ex) {}
                }

            /*****************************************************/
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

            // Close progress dialog
            Dialog.dismiss();

            if (Error != null) {

                uiUpdate.setText("Output : "+Error);

            } else {

                // Show Response Json On Screen (activity)
                uiUpdate.setText( Content );

             /****************** Start Parse Response JSON Data *************/

                String OutputData = "";
                JSONObject jsonResponse;

                try {

                     /****** Creates a new JSONObject with name/value mappings from the JSON string. ********/
                     jsonResponse = new JSONObject(Content);

                     /***** Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONArray. ***/
                     /*******  Returns null otherwise.  *******/
                     JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("Android");

                     /*********** Process each JSON Node ************/

                     int lengthJsonArr = jsonMainNode.length();  

                     for(int i=0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++) 
                     {
                         /****** Get Object for each JSON node.***********/
                         JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);

                         /******* Fetch node values **********/
                         String name       = jsonChildNode.optString("name").toString();
                         String number     = jsonChildNode.optString("number").toString();
                         String date_added = jsonChildNode.optString("date_added").toString();


                         OutputData += " Name           : "+ name +" 
 "
                                     + "Number      : "+ number +" 
 "
                                     + "Time                : "+ date_added +" 
 " 
                                     +"--------------------------------------------------
";


                    }
                 /****************** End Parse Response JSON Data *************/    

                     //Show Parsed Output on screen (activity)
                     jsonParsed.setText( OutputData );


                 } catch (JSONException e) {

                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }


             }
        }

    }

}
```

rest_full_webservice.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fillViewport="true"
  android:background="#FFFFFF"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <EditText
        android:paddingTop="20px"
        android:id="@+id/serverText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
    <Button
        android:paddingTop="10px"
        android:id="@+id/GetServerData"
        android:text="Restful Webservice Call"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    /> 
    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="20px"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Server Response (JSON): " />
    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="16px"
        android:id="@+id/output"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Output : Click on button to get server data." />

    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="20px"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Parsed JSON : " />
    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="16px"
        android:id="@+id/jsonParsed"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

manifest.xml don't forgot to add internet permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

I think you required OAUth 2.0,
you can get sample from https://github.com/cbitstech/xsi-android
scribe library is the best way to do this.